# EF Core xml column new lines lost on store

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have to insert some data in an xml column. The data that I have to insert has new lines in them. However after the EF core stores the data the new lines are lost.

Is there a functionality to preserve the new lines?

I do not want to encrypt the new lines and decrypt them every time.

What would be the best way to encrypt the new line? The data comes from a text area so all the text are accepted.

Comment: By "new lines" do you mean something like "carriage return/white space"?  To be frank with you, these are "display details" and really not a part of the data you store in the database.  You should be glad the (space wasting) whitespace is being removed.   Having said that, you can look at this article.  https://sqlrambling.net/2017/12/29/preserving-white-space-in-empty-xml-elements/       But again, you should NOT (IMHO) trying to store "display concerns" in your database.

Comment: What do you consider to be new line characters? Carriage returns (`x0D`) and linefeeds (`x0A`) are normalised to linefeeds as part of the XML deserialization process as per [2.11 End-of-line Handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-line-ends).

Comment: I need the preserve the new lines because on retrive the values have to be displayed with the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the xml column does not support new lines in the attribute. However in the element it does support it.

So I had to change storing the value from attribute to an element.

The reason I chose the attribute was to reduce the size of the xml.